# Don't forget to review the posts!

Tags: discussion, reviewing-behavior

After a (somewhat large) break, I have been more present in the last days. I noticed that many questions are flagged and get onto the Review Queue.

However a few hours or even a few days later, I notice that the questions are not only opened, but stay by 2-3 close votes.

We need 5 votes to close a question. However in a review process, if enough people (also 5, IIRC) vote to leave the question opened, the close votes are discarded and the question stays open.

Yet, those questions stay in-between.

Please remember to check the Review Queue, and decide. You may want to keep it open. Or close it, that's your choice. But it's better to try to take a decision, than staying in an undefined state.

If you need some help, you may have a look at the [help](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions).

Comment: If three people vote to leave the question open, it is removed from the close votes queue, but the close votes aren't affected. Close votes [age away after time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250223/323179).

Answer (score 9):

> But it's better to try to take a decision, than staying in an undefined state.

No.

I feel like we have closed legitimate questions, and let bad ones slip, because of this. If I see a question for which I can't say whether it is fitting or not for the site, I don't touch it. I'd rather not judge what I don't understand,  otherwise I could make a mistake that would be hard to fix.

If you cast the last vote on closing a legitimate question, it takes five people with 3k+ rep to undo your mess. Even worse, you could delete an answer, which takes even more rep just to be able to vote for undoing. Please make sure to understand the consequences of what you are doing. The skip button is a legitimate choice in the review queue.

Comment: It is if you are doubting. But the review queue is there to ensure the quality of the questions and answers on Worldbuilding. 'Skip' cannot be a systematic choice. Questions that have more than 15 answers, all equally valid point to some issue. Ignoring it won't improve the site.

Comment: This sounds like a variation on "analysis paralysis". You can't take an action unless you know FOR SURE that it is the right one. Yet isn't the voting there to specifically prevent that? Sure, "5 people could be wrong" but the vote casting is there to minimise this. If one should only ever vote if the decision would be completely clear, then isn't the X votes needed completely superficial? Note that I'm not advocating to vote on anything and everything if you don't have the complete expertise but I don't think votes should be squirreled away, either.

Comment: Bravo! I agree. I feel the same way. There are questions which I am uncertain whether they fit the site or not, the sensible thing is leave them alone. Legitimate questions are closed and bad ones do slip through. SE has the skip button there for a reason. The Hippocratic Oath rightly says: "First of all, do no harm." Glad you're standing up for commonsense.

Answer (score 1):

If something has 2-3 close votes after a few days, then a decision *was* taken by those who saw it in the queue and that decision was to leave it open.

It's a vote, and the vote can go either way. Just because something is in the queue is not a reason to close it. It should be closed on its flaws or merits and it takes 5 votes to do so for a reason, it's not a railroad to closure once it's in the queue. So those questions don't "stay in-between", they stay open.